# Spring doesn't start when configured to use https

Tags: spring

I followed this guide:
http://nemerosa.ghost.io/2015/07/06/enabling-ssl-with-spring-boot/

Basically ran this command in my project's home dir:

```
keytool -genkey -alias ontrack -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650 \  
    -dname "CN=Damien Coraboeuf, OU=Ontrack, O=Nemerosa, L=Brussels, ST=Unknown, C=BE" \
    -keypass ontrack \
    -storepass ontrack
```

And pasted this to my `application.yml`:

```
server:  
  port: 443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: ontrack
    key-store: "keystore.p12"
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: ontrack
    key-password: ontrack
```

And this is the generated log:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 443 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.zimperium.server.ZimperiumApplication.init(ZimperiumApplication.java:59)
    at com.zimperium.server.appdirect.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)

2017-10-10 22:22:45.656 ERROR [appdirect,,,] 121 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

This is running inside a Docker container so there's no chance the port is already being used (and it isn't the only port I tried).

Answer (score 0):

On some *nix system, 1 to 1024 ports can only be used by root privilege. You have two options:

1. Run your application by root (not recommended)
2. Run your application on port > 1024 (may be 8443)